# How to conditionally prevent user from navigating to other tab in mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I have an angular component which uses an angular material tab group.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> <app-comp1></app-comp1> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> <app-comp2></app-comp2> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> <app-comp3></app-comp3> </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In a certain tab, user can do some changes and save. If user did some changes and tries to navigate to another tab without saving, I want to ask the user for confirmation to discard changes before navigating to the other tab.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: if you are using routing you can use `CanDeactivate` router guard.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2013

Comment: Let's say user did some changes in tab one and then tries to navigate to tab two, you can bind the second and third tab label with a (click) event which check if user has done some work or not, if yes then show the pop up which either saves the data(either save directly or route the user back to tab one) or discard, if discard then remove the user's activities so on clicking any other tab it does not show the pop up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607394/angular-material-tab-prevent-tab-change-of-mat-tab-group-if-the-form-in-curren

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If there is no solution today then i can offer you some trick based on monkey patching:

**template.html**

```html
<mat-tab-group #tabs>
  ...
</mat-tab-group>
```

**component.ts**

```typescript
import { MatTabGroup, MatTabHeader, MatTab } from '@angular/material';
...
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implement OnInit {
  @ViewChild('tabs') tabs: MatTabGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tabs._handleClick = this.interceptTabChange.bind(this);
  }

  interceptTabChange(tab: MatTab, tabHeader: MatTabHeader, idx: number) {
    const result = confirm(`Do you really want to leave the tab ${idx}?`);

    return result && MatTabGroup.prototype._handleClick.apply(this.tabs, arguments);
  }
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/dLUCQcWK3Y5pnsPitAqe)**

Comment: This works perfectly, but can you explain a bit more how this works? is this part of Angular / Material / Html / Javascript?

Comment: This does work to prevent tab change, but the tab information it receives is for the NEW tab requested, not the previously active tab. So in my case this is no better than the built-in tab changed event.

Comment: @GeekyMonkey You can get that previously active tab through `this.tabs.selectedIndex`

Comment: Thank you @yurzui. This is genius and exactly what I needed. One thing to note that might help someone else is for `arguments`, make sure to pass along the tab, tabHeader and idx where @yurizui has noted arguments. `apply(this.tabs, [tab, tabHeader, idx])`

Comment: Wasn't working for me until I used  `ngAfterViewInit` rather than ngOnInit

Comment: @Dodi Consider adding `static: true` to `@ViewChild` decorator if you're on Angular 9 and above

Comment: This unfortunately will not work in case of using keyboard to focus and change tab

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has stopped working for me in the latest vue version.

Another option is to set the other tabs to disabled when the active tab is in a state that is incomplete.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Form">Form Here</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Result" >Result Here</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace [Yurzui solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51354403) by using Subjects, as to use a modal instead of a `window.comfirm()`. This will work in Angular 17 with RxJS lib. (Hope it helps GeekyMonkey and others)

- Create a new `Subject<void>()` variable.
- Create a function for your (click) in `file.html`.
- Put `this.NameOfSubject.next();` in the function.
- In `NgInit`, write the line from the other answer.
- Add a ViewChild like they did but modified:

  ```
  @ViewChild('tabs', {static: true}) tabs: MatTabGroup;
  ```
- In the second function (`interceptTabChange()`), you can call your modal window opening method, then subscribe to your subject.
- In the subscribe method, you can do:

  ```
  MatTabGroup.prototype._handleClick.apply(this.tabs, [tab, tabHeader, idx])
  ```

Don't forget to create your modal in your `.html` file where you have your button with the (click) calling the method you created before.

Then, the code should open your custom modal window and clicking on the button where you set in the new click function, and will allow the user to change tab.

Comment: Please edit this answer from a computer, it's absolutely unreadable as it.