# Angular Material Tab Group - prevent tab change

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material

I use the [Angular Material Tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) and need a hook to check if the user can change the tab (form is un/saved). I couldn't find any API functionality to prevent the tab change. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can use Disable input in MatTab to control. When form is unsaved, set the MatTab > Disable to true. You can refer to https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTab

Comment: From the (given) UX flow it should be clickable and when the form is unsaved, the tab should not change and a modal overlay will be displayed with the option to save or to abort. While when clicking "abort" the tab should not change and of course as long as the user hasn't clicked "save".

Comment: I think I'll go with the nav tab bar and implement the special behaviour on my own
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607394/angular-material-tab-prevent-tab-change-of-mat-tab-group-if-the-form-in-curren/56607398#56607398

Answer (score 8):

I used the solution from AlessHo, however it didn't work for me that way. I had to change the function assigned to `_handleClick`, returning a boolean didn't do the trick.

Here's my solution:

Add `@ViewChild(MatTabGroup) tabs: MatTabGroup;` to the class.

Note the type parameter in place of the `#tabGroup` reference. It worked with it as well, but our tests didn't. `tabs` was undefined in the tests, but it worked with the type selector.

Next, I implemented `AfterViewInit`, because in the `OnInit`, the tab group was not reliably initialized:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    // Just to be sure
    if (!this.tabs) {
        throw Error('ViewChild(MatTabGroup) tabs; is not defined.');
    }

    // Returning just a boolean did nothing, but this works:

    // 1. Save the click handler for later
    const handleTabClick = this.tabs._handleClick;

    // 2. Replace the click handler with our custom function
    this.tabs._handleClick = (tab, header, index) => {

        // 3. Implement your conditional logic in canDeactivateTab()
        // (return the boolean here)
        if (this.canDeactivateTab()) {

            // 4. If the tab *should* be changed, call the 'old' click handler
            handleTabClick.apply(this.tabs, [tab, header, index]);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this, but I'm having issues on running my custom code, how would I run something after making the tabchange?

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but I'd try to do it just after step 4 `handleTabClick.apply`.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. In my case I would not allow the user to move to another tab until he fills all mandatory details.

Finally I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354135/how-to-conditionally-prevent-user-from-navigating-to-other-tab-in-mat-tab-group/51354403#51354403) different from `(selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)"` which is the one that has been used:

1. Add `@ViewChild('tabGroup') tabs: MatTabGroup;` in your class;
2. add #tabGroup to `<mat-tab-group #tabGroup> .. </mat-tab-group>` in your HTML code.
3. Add `import {MatTabGroup, MatTab, MatTabHeader } from '@angular/material';` to your class;
4. Add `this.tabs._handleClick = this.myTabChange.bind(this);` in `ngOnInit` function;
5. Add below function which allows tab change or not, and is able to get the tab index number:

```js
myTabChange(tab: MatTab, tabHeader: MatTabHeader, idx: number) {    
    var result = false;    
    // here I added all checks/conditions ; if everything is Ok result is changed to true
    // ==> this way the tab change is allowed.
    return result;    
}
```

Cheers !

Comment: Should be `import { MatTabGroup, MatTab, MatTabHeader } from '@angular/material/tabs';`

Comment: Nice solution with two little hooks:
the _handleClick(...)-function returns void! Your boolean result will be ignored.
You can solve this by combining this solution with 
template: [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex"
in your function: if (/* your checks here*/) { this.selectedTabIndex = idx; }
Another hook is that the viewchild is accessible in ngAfterViewInit. So put the 'this.tabs._handleClick = this.myTabChange.bind(this)' into ngAfterViewInit().
that did it for me.